# How to contact CBP at Vancouver Pacific Central station?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, train-stations, vancouver, pre-clearance

The CBP website makes no mention of any contact details of the CBP at Vancouver Pacific Central station. I tried calling the station itself (ViaRail number), but they weren't helpful.

Does anyone know how to reach them? I have a question that specifically concerns entry into the US at that location.

Comment: But if you already contacted the station, what are you asking for?

Comment: @Johns-305 CBP staff - this was the ViaRail number

Comment: @chx Shall I post it as a new question or edit this one?

Comment: @MarkMayo see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Central_Station: "Passengers bound for the United States go through United States border preclearance prior to boarding in Vancouver."

Comment: Yes train passenger are pre-cleared and it's extremely annoying because you need to arrive early for the train this way. And there's no GE machine, you need to talk to an actual person for border crossing like a peasant ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per this [discussion](http://www.visajourney.com/forums/topic/311896-poe-at-amtrak-train-station/):

> I called the customs and border folks at the airport to see if they could give me a number for the train station. He said the train station doesn't have a number, and all the same people from the airport work there.

So if you call [preclearance](https://www.cbp.gov/border-security/ports-entry/operations/preclearance) at the YVR airport at (604) 278-7422 then you will talk to the staff who will meet you at the train station. This makes sense, there are only two trains a day, it's pointless to maintain an entire CBP office at the station.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is probably https://www.cbp.gov/contact:

> If you are unable to find the information you need [on cbp.gov], the CBP INFO Center is open Monday-Friday between 9 a.m. and 4 p.m. Eastern time. You can ask your question via email or by calling 1-877-CBP-5511 (877-227-5511). If you are outside the U.S. you must call 202-325-8000. (Telecommunications device for the hearing impaired: 1-800-877-8339 or https://www.federalip.us/)

Even if your question is specific to preclearance in the train station, the central help line should be able to find someone who knows the answer.